# How Do I Set Up Blueprints that are Not Really Designed to Model Cars

Tags: modeling

So I have really wanted to make a 2016 Camaro SS but there are no really good blueprints for it. So Im using regular images that give the front,side,top, and back, however, it still does not quite work. How do I set up them in a way that they will work? [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *What* doesn't work?

Comment: When I try use the 3d cursor to line up the windshields like clicking the top of it, it fits the top and front but not the side.

Comment: You don't use these pictures, that's so boomer. You use real photographs as a reference, best made from the same camera. Then you make a several sequences from them and 3d track them by hand marking key points and you solve for camera position. For each frame you get a camera with background image and you model to that. It's the most accurate and detailed approach you can do apart from actual 3d scanning.

Answer (score -1):

Add two pics at the same time, set them to fit in the same view, then select the side where you want to see the actual background picture.
[image]

Comment: Ok so the front and side work, but the top view does not match the nose of the car like the front and side to. My 3D cursor is way off from the nose on the top view, but i can't scale up my top view because then it would mess up everything else